# Migrate from dojo to standard bootstrap admin dashboard theme

Tags: dojo

I am using a php dojo v1.4 project with mysql as backend.

The UI looks very basic.

I need to migrate this project to a standard bootstrap admin theme.

What are the steps I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

If backend and general architecture of your application will remain the same, I'd suggest you to start building new UI from the scratch. When it finished, write missing functions, which were previously implemented with dojo using jquery (which comes with bootstrap) or whatever you like. 
I assume, that you are not going to use dojo anymore.

If you are facing some specific difficulties, you'd better provide more details in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.